# Configure TortoiseGitPlink to autoload key for a specific URL

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit, plink

I am using GoCD for continuous delivery and have a Material that uses a git repository as the source.  I originally had the URL as SSH but it was hanging.  So I switch it to HTTPS, but the repo has a submodule that uses SSH so I'm stuck figuring out getting SSH working.  Debugging it, it appears to be hanging on the submodule update, (specifically it looks like TortoiseGitPlink.exe in the process tree).  So I'm guessing it's trying to prompt for a key (but it's running as a service).

I'm using [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) and have `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe`.  Most of the time I use `pageant.exe` to load my key files, but I can't for this since `git.exe` is being launched from a service, not in the active desktop.  I can't configure `puttykeyfile` in the git config of the repo because the repo is cloned on the fly.

Is there somewhere I can globally configure `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` to use a specified key file for a specific SSH path?  I'm using BitBucket so I need different SSH keys depending on the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found the answer here:

https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html#tgit-ssh-faq-defaultkey

If you are using `plink.exe` or `TortoiseGitPlink.exe`, you can load `putty.exe` and create saved sessions, either the Default Session or host-named sessions and specify the key to use.  See the above link for details. Of course, your key must not have a password.

Note that putty.exe stores sessions in the current user registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions` so if your service is loaded under a specific account, you will need to login with that account and configure `putty.exe`.